# Optimising code for performance Concrete5/PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to be as efficient as a I can using a CSV to import users to a CMS called "Concrete5 - Version 8.2.1". I have a list of 700+ users and i've created an upload screen to take in a CSV and process the creation of new users. Code below.

Now I have ran the code several times (and then removed the users) to test how long its going to take for users of the system to generate a large list of customers. Currently its taking around 16.34 seconds per user!! which is obviously a huge amount of time when you're importing 700+ (3Hrs 24Mins total it took).

Can anyone make any suggestions for optimisations to speed things up, any rookie mistakes I've made. If you can explain why that would really help my understanding.

```
public function handleSubmit()
{
$l = new Logger(LOG_TYPE_EXCEPTIONS);
$l->info("");
$l->info("Start User Import");
$recordProcess = [];
$eachUserCount = 0;

$RegionEntities = Express::getList('region');

$FacilityEntities = Express::getList('facility');

$this->connImport = $this->getDB();
$this->entityManager = \Core::make('database / orm')->entityManager();

$userRegistrationService = \Core::make('\Concrete\Core\User\RegistrationServiceInterface');
$userinfo = array();
$htmlReturn = "";

$token = $this->app->make('token');

if (!$token->validate()) {
    throw new UserMessageException($token->getErrorMessage());
}

$file = $this->request->files->get('file');
if (!($file instanceof UploadedFile)) {
    throw new UserMessageException(t('File not received . '));
}

if (!$file->isValid()) {
    throw new UserMessageException($file->getErrorMessage());
}
if ($file->getPathname()) {
    $fh = fopen($file->getPathname(), 'r');

} else {
    return "File path not found";
}
if ($fh) {

    $sql = "TRUNCATE TABLE Users";

    $result = $this->connImport->query($sql);

    $result = $this->loadDataReplace($this->connImport, $file, 'UserDatabase . Users', 2);

    if ($result) {
        $dataLoaded = "Data loaded successfully into Users table\n";
        $sql = "call process_Users()";

        $result2 = $this->connImport->query($sql);
        if ($result2) {
            $dataLoaded .= "Users processed successfully. ";
        } else {
            $dataLoaded .= "There was a problem processing the Users: " . mysqli_error($this->connImport);
        }
    } else {
        $dataLoaded = 'There was a problem loading the data into Users table . ' . mysqli_error($this->connImport);
    }

    $htmlReturn .= "<table class='table display'>
                <thead>
                <tr>
                <td>User Name</td>
                <td>User Email</td>
                <td>User Password</td>
                <td>User Role</td>
                <td>Created Successfully?</td>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody class='user_import_scroll'>";


    $group = Group::getByName("Overall User Group");
    $dentalRegion = "Regional";
    $dentalFacility = "Facility";

    $groupRegion = Group::getByName($Region);

    $groupFacility = Group::getByName($Facility);

    $sql = "SELECT id,email, concat(id, forename) as pwd, role,regionAccess, facilityAccess, regions, facilities, if(regions like 'HQ % ','HQ','') as HQ FROM UsersDatabase.Users_combined";

    $result = $this->connImport->query($sql);

    $RegionEntity = [];

    foreach ($RegionEntities as $entity) {
        $RegionEntity[$entity->getRegionName()] = $entity->getId();
    }

    $FacilitiesEntity = [];

    foreach ($FacilityEntities as $facilityEntity) {
        $FacilitiesEntity[$facilityEntity->getFacilityName()] = $facilityEntity->getId();
    }


    while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $reg = false;
        $htmlReturn .= "<tr>";
        $userinfo = ['uName' => $data['id'], 'uEmail' => $data['email'], 'uPassword' => $data['pwd']];

        $ui = \Core::make('Concrete\Core\User\UserInfoRepository')->getByName($data['id']);
        if (!$ui) {

            $reg = $userRegistrationService->create($userinfo);

            $roles = explode(",", $data['role']);
            $role_string = '';

            foreach ($roles as $role) {
                if (strpos($role_string, $role) === false) {
                    $role_string .= $role . " , ";
                }
            }

            $reg->SetAttribute('user_role', $role_string);

            $u = \Core::make('Concrete\Core\User\UserInfoRepository')->getByName($data['id']);

            $user = $u->getUserObject();

            if (!$user->inGroup($group)) {
                $user->enterGroup($group);
            }

            if (!$user->inGroup($groupRegion)) {

                if ($data['regionAccess'] == $Region) {
                    $user->enterGroup($groupRegion);
                }
            }
            if (!$user->inGroup($groupFacility)) {
                if ($data['facilityAccess'] == $Facility) {
                    $user->enterGroup($groupFacility);
                }
            }

            $region_entries = [];

            $regions = explode("#", $data['regions']);

            foreach ($regions as $region_name) {
                foreach ($RegionEntity as $key => $value) {

                    if ($region_name == $key) {

                        $region_entries[] = $this->entityManager->getRepository('Concrete\Core\Entity\Express\Entry')->findOneById($value);
                    }
                }
            }


            $u->setAttribute('region', $region_entries);


            $facility_entries = [];

            $facilities = explode("#", $data['facilities']);

            foreach ($facilities as $facility_name) {
                foreach ($FacilitiesEntity as $key => $value) {

                    if ($facility_name == $key) {
                        $facility_entries[] = $this->entityManager->getRepository('Concrete\Core\Entity\Express\Entry')->findOneById($value);
                    }
                }
            }

            $u->setAttribute('facility', $facility_entries);

            if ($data['HQ'] == "HQ") {

                $u->setAttribute('hq', 'Yes');
            }

            $u->setAttribute('agreement_check ', 0);

        }

        $htmlReturn .= "<td>" . $userinfo['uName'] . "</td>";
        $htmlReturn .= "<td>" . $userinfo['uEmail'] . "</td>";
        $htmlReturn .= "<td>" . $userinfo['uPassword'] . "</td>";
        $htmlReturn .= "<td>" . rtrim($data['role'], " , ") . "</td>";

        if ($reg) {
            $htmlReturn .= "<td><span class='fa fa - check'></span></td>";
        } else {
            $htmlReturn .= "<td><span class='fa fa - close'></span> User already exists </td>";
        }
        $htmlReturn .= "</tr>";

    }
    fclose($fh);

} else {
    return "No filename found, refresh page and try again";
}
$htmlReturn .= "</tbody>";
$htmlReturn .= "</table>";
$htmlReturn .= "<div class='alert alert - info'><strong>Notice</strong> " . $dataLoaded . "</div>";

$l->info("");
$l->info("End User Import");
return $this->app->make(ResponseFactoryInterface::class)->json($htmlReturn);
}
```